# Without form tag, I am getting the ans for sum of 2 nos using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Friends,
Plz check out my code and tell me why am not getting the result if I use form tag.
When I remove the form tag, I get the result. why can't I get the expected result if I use form tag ? Your suggestions can help me understand this better !! thank u ..

CODE :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ADDITION OF 2 NOS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function add() {
        var x=document.getElementById("value1").value;
        var y=document.getElementById("value2").value;
        var z=x+y;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=z;
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <form name="form1" id="form1_id">
            ENTER NO 1 : <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"><br>
            ENTER NO 2 : <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="add()">
            <p id="result"></p>
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably receive the result, but when you click in a submit button inside a form you let the browser automatically redirect to another page. You can prevent that by calling `[Event]#preventDefault()` or returning `false` on the submit callback

Comment: try to multiply x and y with 1 to force numbers. your z concatenates two strings at the moment.

Comment: @NinaScholz In my language it means "in", with accent 'ó' it means "us & we" or "tokens".

Comment: @FREEZE, what is *my language*?

Comment: @NinaScholz My main speaking/writting language: Portuguese (Brazilian), although I actually try to write more English than my main language that is bad. I'm getting always better at English

Comment: So, how does the answers help you?

Comment: @NinaScholz "nos" are numbers

Answer (score 1):

You need numerical values. `document.getElementById("value1").value` returns a string.

```
var x = +document.getElementById("value1").value;
//     ^ cast to number
```

To prevent submitting, you need to include

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
```

as well.

```js
function add() {
    var x = +document.getElementById("value1").value;
    var y = +document.getElementById("value2").value;
    var z = x + y;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = z;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" id="form1_id" onsubmit="return false;">
ENTER NO 1 : <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"><br>
ENTER NO 2 : <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="add()">
<p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Op user said he isn't receiving the result. What he's doing is concatenation, and works because the browser handles plus arithmetic as concatenation when there's a string. So, the problem is when he's declaring a FORM wrapping the elements

Comment: @FREEZE sure but also mentioned "sum of two numbers" in the title which can't be the same as concatenation of two strings. anyway, got your point.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 He/she didn't ask about the sum, though.

Comment: @FREEZE agree with you. i'm just pointing out that he cant get sum of numbers, with or without FORM wrapper, by concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `submit` element is causing the form to submit. It does the add() then submits the form. To prevent that, use `onsubmit="return false;"` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function add() 
{
 var x=document.getElementById("value1").value;
 var y=document.getElementById("value2").value;
 var z=x+y;
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=z;
}
</script>

<body>
<center>
<form name="form1" id="form1_id" onsubmit="return false;">
ENTER NO 1 : <input type="text" name="value1" id="value1"><br>
ENTER NO 2 : <input type="text" name="value2" id="value2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="add()">
<p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

Second of all, you're doing concatenation in your `add()` function. If you want to really add the numbers, use

```
var z = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
```

in your `add()` function. If you expect decimals use `parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: Correct, and it's also possible to prevent the default action of the browser by calling `[Event]#preventDefault` (in this inline callback, the event object is stored at `event`), and you can easily convert these values to number by using unary `+`: `+value`

Comment: the necessary event is not click, but submit, you are mixing up with buttons.

Comment: @NinaScholz onclick works as well, but you're right -- for correctness' sake the most accurate answer is changing what happens on submit rather than click. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, when that submit button is clicked and it's present in one (or more) form(s) a redirect happens. This redirect happens because the form will be submitted after that click.

So, to stop this redirect you need to prevent the default action of the browser to this form at its submit event, e.g., give it a callback, then return exact `false` at this function, or call `[Event]#preventDefault`.

```
form1 = document.form1
var form1

form1.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
}, false)
```

Done. Note: your sum actually concatenates strings. I'd also note that the `HTMLFormElement#submit` method wouldn't trigger this submit event, and that's good.